# JavaScript String Generator

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop

Great people of Stack, I need your help. I'm currently working on a project that creates a Lorem Ipsum string for people to use. The problem is, I've laid the basis so to speak but now I'm at a loss as to where to go next. I'm really rather new to JavaScript and as such, struggling quite a bit.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var gordonTime = function(){
                    var lines = new Array(
                        "It's raw", 
                        "Oh, for god's sake", 
                        "Is that the best you can do?", 
                        "Disgusting.", 
                        "You donkey!", 
                        "This isn't cooking", 
                        "Fine cuisine", 
                        "Get out", 
                        "Hells Kitchen", 
                        "Bland"
                    );
                    var paraAmount = prompt("How many paragraphs do you need?");
                    var phraseAmount = prompt("How many words to a paragraph?");
                    for(i = 0; i <= phraseAmount; i++){
                            document.write(lines[i] + " ");
                        }
                }
            </script>
```

At the moment, the browser currently prompts the user for the amount of Paragraphs they require, followed by how many words they would like contained in each paragraph. The problem I have is that I just don't know how to partain the word count to the number of paragraphs, I just don't know where to start programming wise, does anyone have any references they could give me to get started with this. The code currently references the array and produces said amount of phrases accurately.

Basically, I need the code to identify the number of paragraphs they require from the prompt, then work out how many of the phrases to put into that paragraph. Any ideas guys? Any help would be brilliant. Thanks.

Comment: I think you are lacking a working **concept** for you requirements. You should know and tell us what happens for example when he chooses  10 word per paragraph (as you lines don't have 10 words). Also you are making a for-loop by using the entered phraseAmount. What happens now when the user enters 50 paragraphs and you try to access lines[20]? It will crash...

Comment: What happens is the script just prints out "undefined" which is fine for now because there will be more information added to the array in time, it doesn't crash, it just displays that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too sure if this fits your requirements and the js isn't the best but it will generate random phrases.

You could alter it to enumerate the lines array and just keep repeating until the words count has been reached, or you can select them at random. It's totally up to you. You'd just need to change the `GetRandomPhraseWords` method to get the next one in the array (or first if last is reached);

**With** jQuery [Example](http://jsbin.com/eJijODEX/3/)

```
     var gordonTime = function () {

     var lines = new Array(
         "It's raw",
         "Oh, for god's sake",
         "Is that the best you can do?",
         "Disgusting.",
         "You donkey!",
         "This isn't cooking",
         "Fine cuisine",
         "Get out",
         "Hells Kitchen",
         "Bland");

     var paragraphCount = prompt("How many paragraphs do you need?");
     var wordsPerParagraph = prompt("How many words to a paragraph?");

     for (var i = 0; i < paragraphCount; i++) {
         var paragraph = $('<p />');         

         AppendWordsTo(paragraph, wordsPerParagraph, 0);

         $('body').append(paragraph);
     }

     function AppendWordsTo(paragraph, wordsPerParagraph, currentWordCount) {
         var phrase = GetRandomPhraseWords();

         for (var i = 0; i < phrase.length; i++) {
             if (currentWordCount < wordsPerParagraph) {
                 paragraph.append(phrase[i] + " ");
                 currentWordCount++;
             }
         }

         if (currentWordCount < wordsPerParagraph) {
             AppendWordsTo(paragraph, wordsPerParagraph, currentWordCount);
         }
     }

     function GetRandomPhraseWords() {
         var randomPhrase = lines[Math.floor(Math.random() * lines.length)];
         var phraseWords = randomPhrase.split(" ");

         return phraseWords;
     }
 };

 gordonTime();
```

**Without** jQuery [Example](http://jsbin.com/aXUpEmU/1/)

```
var gordonTime = function () {
     var lines = new Array(
         "It's raw",
         "Oh, for god's sake",
         "Is that the best you can do?",
         "Disgusting.",
         "You donkey!",
         "This isn't cooking",
         "Fine cuisine",
         "Get out",
         "Hells Kitchen",
         "Bland");

     var paragraphCount = prompt("How many paragraphs do you need?");
     var wordsPerParagraph = prompt("How many words to a paragraph?");

     GenerateParagraphs(paragraphCount, wordsPerParagraph);

     function GenerateParagraphs(paragraphCount, wordsPerParagraph)
     {       
         var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

         for (var i = 0; i < paragraphCount; i++) {
             var paragraph = document.createElement('p');

             AppendWordsTo(paragraph, wordsPerParagraph, 0);         

           body.appendChild(paragraph);
         }   
     }

     function AppendWordsTo(paragraph, wordsPerParagraph, currentWordCount) {
         var phrase = GetRandomPhraseWords();

         for (var i = 0; i < phrase.length; i++) {
             if (currentWordCount < wordsPerParagraph) {
                 paragraph.innerHTML += (phrase[i] + " ");
                 currentWordCount++;
             }
         }

         if (currentWordCount < wordsPerParagraph) {
             AppendWordsTo(paragraph, wordsPerParagraph, currentWordCount);
         }
     }

     function GetRandomPhraseWords() {
         var randomPhrase = lines[Math.floor(Math.random() * lines.length)];
         var phraseWords = randomPhrase.split(" ");

         return phraseWords;
     }
 };

 gordonTime();
```

Comment: You are using **jQuery** without pointing it out as the question author did not mention jQuery you should explain that he would need to include it in order to make your code work.

Comment: Ah good point, what RononDex said :) - You'll need to reference the jQuery library for the $ selector to work. if you wanted to just use JS you'll need to get/create the element, and change the paragraph.append line to concatenate the innerHTML/innerText. - I'd reference jQuery though.. it's easier =)

Answer (score 0):

You can split the words of a pargraphs using the spaces:

```
 var lines = new Array(
                        "It's raw", 
                        "Oh, for god's sake", 
                        "Is that the best you can do?", 
                        "Disgusting.", 
                        "You donkey!", 
                        "This isn't cooking", 
                        "Fine cuisine", 
                        "Get out", 
                        "Hells Kitchen", 
                        "Bland"
                    );

var gordonTime = function(){

                    var paraAmount = prompt("How many paragraphs do you need?");
                    var phraseAmount = prompt("How many words to a paragraph?");

                    for(i = 0; i <= paraAmount; i++){
                         var line = lines[i];
                         var words = line.split(" ");

                         var text = "";

                         for (j = 0; j < phraseAmount; j++)
                         {
                            text += words[j] + " ";                            
                         }

                        document.write("<p>" + text + "</p>");
                     }
                }
```

However you would still have to handle the cases where the indexes exceed the array's lengths

Comment: This doesn't work properly. It only ever inputs 1 array value into a paragraph, if the user says they would like 1 paragraph, it would input the first array value before beginning another paragraph even if there 5 phrases to a paragraph for example.

Comment: Then you would have to replace `<p>` from `document.write` with something else. I think I misunderstood your question then. It is really hard for me to understand what you are asking for, can you please explain your issue a bit more detailed then?